# Looking for possibilities to monitor the Azure resources in business application context and not just the resources in silos. Any suggestions?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I have an Azure application consisting of various resources like Logic Apps, Service Bus & Event Grid. As Azure monitor now supports monitoring only the resources involved, are there any solutions that provides application-level monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring serverless resources in Azure has now become way easy as there are several third-party tools to achieve what you're looking for. As this question is just about suggestion, I'll suggest a tool that best matches your context, as I am a part of the development team. You should explore [Serverless360](https://www.serverless360.com/). It is widely used all over the globe to solve the main problem that most of the organisations face: Business-level application management and monitoring.

Serverless360 has a dedicated module for this where you can pile up all your Azure resources that constitute your LoB application. Not only monitoring, but also there are several other options that Azure portal doesn't provide, for which you will have to go for different tools like Service Bus Explorer, Storage account explorer, App insights, New Relic to achieve things. Serverless360 is an all-in-one solution where you no longer have to look for a second tool for your management of Azure resources.

Also, you can take a look at the [top Azure monitoring tools](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/azure-monitoring-tools/) that best suits your needs.